# How to display a QMenu on a QAction trigger

Tags: qt, menu, qaction

I Have a (QT) toolbar in my application which is populated by QAction objects, and one of the QActions has an associated menu. I would like to pop up that menu below the QActions' button when the action is triggered.

I have tried:

```
m_ui->action_NewDataType->menu()->show();
```

but this shows the menu on the left upper corner of the screen, instead of where I want it. How can I show the menu below the QAction button, nicely aligned to the edges of the button?

Comment: `m_ui->action_NewDataType->menu()->move(x,y)`, is that what you're looking for? You can also call `m_ui->action_NewDataType->menu()->exec(QPoint(x,y))`, that way you won't have to move it first.

Comment: Yes, but how do I find (x,y)?

Comment: is it OK for you to implement using QToolButton, instead of QToolbar to achive  ?

Comment: No, not really, it's used in a menu too (the same action)

Comment: Ok, problem solved: `QWidget* w = m_ui->mainToolBar->widgetForAction(m_ui->action_NewDataType);
    m_ui->action_NewDataType->menu()->popup(w->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, w->height())));`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6003452/1387438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved:

```
 QWidget* w = m_ui->mainToolBar->widgetForAction(m_ui->action_NewDataType);
 m_ui->action_NewDataType->menu()->popup(w->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, w->height())))
```